# Getting rid of Parentheses of Dict and unwanted words[Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

As working on a program using Dict in Python, I am getting a format other than required: the code is as follows:

```
a = {1:2,2:3,3:4,4:8}
print(a.values())
```

getting an output:

```
dict_values([2, 3, 4, 8])
```

here in the output, there is no requirement of "dict_values" and "{ [ ] }", How to remove these wanted things? Actually, I have tried striping but I am thinking of some professional functions to use.

Comment: I just want an output in the form of 2,3,4,8 simple in a iline

Comment: @zwer you need to cast the values to a `str` for `join` to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the * operator to unpack the sequence and print the values.

```
a = {1:2,2:3,3:4,4:8}
print(*a.values())
#2 3 4 8
```

You can also customize the separator and the end using the keyword arguments `sep` and `end` respectively in the call of the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).
For example:

```
print(*a.values(), sep=',')
```

Comment: yes, that works, can you please explain the use of * asterisk here?

Comment: You can find additional details in many questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean

Comment: Add the `sep=','`to the `print`

Answer (score 1):

you could [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) the `dict_values` (which you need to cast to `str`) to a string:

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in a.values())
```